# How do I choose the hyper-parameters for a model to detect different guitar chords?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, object-detection, hyperparameter-optimization, convolution, pooling

I need to build a hand detector that recognizes the chord played by a hand on a guitar.

I read this article [Static Hand Gesture Recognition using Convolutional Neural Network with Data Augmentation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333618617_Static_Hand_Gesture_Recognition_using_Convolutional_Neural_Network_with_Data_Augmentation) that looks like what I need (hand gesture recognition).

I think my task is (from my point of view) a little more difficult than that in [the paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333618617_Static_Hand_Gesture_Recognition_using_Convolutional_Neural_Network_with_Data_Augmentation), because I think it is more difficult to distinguish between two chords than between a punch and a palm.

What I don't understand clearly is how to choose the best parameters for this more complex task: is it better to have more/less convolutional layers? A higher or lower number of poolings? Max or avg pooling?

The input will be more or less like this one:

[image: Input]

There will be a first net (MobileNetV2 trained on EgoHands) that will find the bounding box, crops the image and then passes the saturated blending between the original one and Frei&Chen edges to the second net (unfortunately I don't have a processed picture yet, I will post an example as soon as I get it)

Comment: there is no way to compute analytically what the best parameters are. It is also not trivial to conclude that the task is more complex simply cause for "us" is more difficult to distinguish between 2 chords than palm and punch. It all depends on the data you have. Any concrete picture to share with? Or idea on how you would collect the data in terms of camera, position, lighting, angle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal hyperparameters is usually dependent on your dataset and will differ on a case by case basis. Go for trial and error to determine the hyperparameters that works best for you.

**Few research papers** similar to your use case is listed below.

- [CNN transfer learning for visual guitar chord classification](https://cs230.stanford.edu/projects_fall_2019/reports/26255715.pdf)
- [A Study of Left Fingering Detection Using CNN for Guitar Learning](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/A-Study-of-Left-Fingering-Detection-Using-CNN-for-Kashiwagi-Ochi/db751efb9072840a79cf010856789c314feef164)
- [A 3D Guitar Fingering Assessing System Based on CNN-Hand
  Pose Estimation and SVR-Assessment](https://www.ingentaconnect.com/contentone/ist/ei/2018/00002018/00000009/art00007?crawler=true&mimetype=application/pdf)
- [Applying Deep Learning Techniques to Estimate Patterns of Musical Gesture](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2020.575971/full) : forearm gestures on violin playing